# How can I search the similarity between a cell and the cells of a column, and receive the most similar one? (excel)

Tags: excel, search, return, similarity

I have a cell with a company name. In another column, I have cells with company names, and I am trying to find the most similar cell with the first one that I mentioned before. Also, I have to mention that there is not an exact match, in order to use the EXACT formula. So, I want to find a formula or a VBA way, in order to make a serach at the column, find the most similar cell and return that to me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Find with the xlPart to find the closest.